# How to remove NUL characters from a string using java

Tags: java

I need to read some data from a log file, the log file contains data like below.

[image: File Contains]

In that above image, that file contains some string with NUL characters, I need to do some manipulation with that string, so I want remove that NUL characters in that string. I have tried some logic below to remove that NUL characters, but it didn't work.

My code:

```
String str="Mon Sep 21 14:32:00 IST 2015 =>- =>OpenOffice Writer x ";       
str=str.replace("\0", "");
```

Please tell me the solution to remove that NUL characters. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It seems they are not null.

Comment: convert your string to chars and print out character codes for every string. Looks that there are some not-null symbols, which are shown in your editor as null symbols.

Comment: As @RafaelOsipov proposed, try something like `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(str.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF8"))));`.